# Javascript variable value not refreshing in alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to fix this. The issue is when i select Bangalore and choose any name from 2nd level select and click on button than result is fine, now without refreshing page i choose Hyderabad and a value from 2nd level select and click on button it is still showing value from Bangalore's 2nd level value in alert.

**Code:**

```
<div class="Banglore">
    <select class="second-level-select" id="start_1">
        <option value="">-Select Your Area-</option>
        <option value="Mettuguda">Mettuguda</option>
        <option value="Lingampally">Lingampally</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="Hydrabad" >
    <select class="second-level-select" id="start_2">
        <option value="">-Select Your Area-</option>
        <option value="A F Hospital">A F Hospital</option>
        <option value="Abbur">Abbur</option>
    </select>
```

**Script:**

```
function startAjax() {
    var a1 = $("#start_1").val();
    var a2 = $("#start_2").val();
    if(a1 != ''){
        var b = a1;
    }else{
        var b = a2;
    }

    alert(b);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#Rank').bind('change', function() {

    var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements

    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected

        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }

}).trigger('change');
});
```

for more detail: http://jsfiddle.net/72pbbsfy/2/
Thanks for help!

Comment: Well you fiddle is not set up right, problem 1.

Comment: Second issue, that first select is not the one you are reading the value of.... Code above does not match the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.startAjax = function() {
       var rank = $("#Rank").val();
        var a1 = $("#start_1").val();
        var a2 = $("#start_2").val();
        var b;
        if (rank === 'Banglore') {
            b = a1;
        } else if (rank === 'Hydrabad') {
            b = a2;
        } else {
            b = 'not selected'
        }

        alert(b);

    }
```

Comment: could be written cleaner :) (without global functions, group the var statements, use switch case, less hard coding...) buy this will work....

Comment: In looking at user1986882's code base, this probably suites him well.